# Was the al aqusa mosque that prophet saw in his night dream the same alaqusa we have today or a different mosque in jerusalem?

Tags: surat-al-isra

As Salam Aleikhum brothers and sisters I want a clear understanding regarding the prophets night journey and vision I understand he had a journey from mecca to jerusalem but the present al aqusa and dome of the rock where non existent during his time before his time during prophet Ishas time there was a temple of the jews so which al aqusa did the prophet see in his dreams in Syria there is mosques one also called white mosque I also know he went up to heaven did he see a alaqusa in heaven going by real history.Can you explain to me the night journey like as if I am with the prophet right now thank you jazak allahu khair.

Comment: The rock was present and the night journey is considered as having been a journey in the physical meaning by the majority of scholars.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding on this matter:

"Masjid" literally refers to "place of prostration" derived from the same root words (س ج د) as Sujud/Sajdah (prostration). A Masjid is any designated place where Muslims gather to pray. It is not defined by any building/structure.

Although the building constructions as we know them today may not have existed during the time of the Prophet (ﷺ) [so these are not what he would've seen] and definitely landscapes change over time, he still saw that same area that we know of Al Aqsa and its surroundings.

Allah (ﷻ) said, سبحان الذي أسرى بعبده ليلا من المسجد الحرام إلى المسجد الأقصى الذي باركنا حوله لنريه من آياتنا إنه هو السميع البصير (Exalted is He who took His Servant by night from al-Masjid al-Haram to al-Masjid al- Aqsa, whose surroundings We have blessed, to show him of Our signs...- Qur'an 17:1.

This is in **Jerusalem**, it is not in Syria.

And FYI - the Jewish temple was already destroyed before then, divine punishment.

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته